# Can a character take both the great weapon fighter and frenzy bonus actions on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack, actions, barbarian

If my character goes into a frenzy rage and as a bonus action I make an attack that reduces a creature to 0 HP, does the great weapon fighter feat activate allowing for a additional attack?

Just wondering because the attack for the feat is a bonus action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

A character can only take **at most one** bonus action in their turn.

Bonus Actions, PHB p. 189:

> You can take **only one bonus action** on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Frenzy, PHB p. 19:

> you can make a single melee weapon attack **as a bonus action** on each of your turns after this one.

Great Weapon Fighter, p. 167:

> On your turn, when you ... reduce a creature to 0 hit points with [a melee weapon], you can make one melee weapon attack **as a bonus action**.

Comment: Path of the berserker is getting more and more underwhelming compared to its counter-parts.

Comment: Against many small opponents, a barbarian will get great usage out of GWF, but against a single creature with lots of hit points, frenzy will be much more effective.

Answer (score 5):

No:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.